# How to make the ext_authz envoy filter work on the istio cluster?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I am trying to add ext_authz filter to istio ingress-gateway for requests authentication. But when I'm adding this filter to cluster it seems like it is not added to envoy configuration, i.e. it is not working.

`apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: authn-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  filters:
    - insertPosition:
        index: FIRST
      listenerMatch:
        portNumber: 433
        listenerType: GATEWAY
        listenerProtocol: HTTP
      filterType: HTTP
      filterName: "envoy.ext_authz"
      filterConfig:
        http_service:
          server-uri:
            uri: http://auth.default.svc.cluster.local:8080
            cluster: outbound|8080||auth.default.svc.cluster.local
            timeout: 2s`

`apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: auth-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - gateway.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "/auth"
      route:
        - destination:
            host: auth.default.svc.cluster.local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out, the problem was caused by the old version of istio deployed on the cluster